# Google Cloud Tool to execute a Python process

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a some processes in python and I would like to execute it on google cloud, but I'm not sure what is the best google cloud tool to do it.

I need to execute it daily automatically (cron) and I need to execute multiple processes by day.

Thanks

Comment: Please improve your question and add some more details. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you'd just want to get a tiny instance on Google Compute Engine. The smallest one is f1-micro -- you get a fraction of a CPU core and if it's all you use, you can currently stay in the free tier. Effectively, you get an infinite ROI!